# Importing WFS Feature in ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, wfs, open-source-gis, ogc

I am trying to Import an open source  WFS Feature in ArcGIS. I have filled all the Options correctly but the Toolbox does not work and I receive error that feature is empty.

How can I correct it?

Here is the link:

https://security.geobasis-bb.de/wss/service/VG-WFS/guest?SERVICE=WFS&REQUEST=GetCapabilities&

I have tried different other open source WFS Features too but none of them work. Even I tried the sample from ESRI but it behaves the same.

http://sampleserver6.arcgisonline.com/arcgis/services/SampleWorldCities/MapServer/WFSServer?request=GetCapabilities&service=WFS&

Comment: Are you using the GP tool "WFS to Feature Class"? Have you tried the "Quick Import" Tool (Data Interoperability) with the same results?

Comment: Yes I have tried both options but none of them work.

Comment: The URL to specify is everything up to and including the?

Comment: When I put this WFS into ArcGIS Pro I recieved an error: Failed to add data, unsupported data type.

Comment: I get a different issue (output Feature class empty).  For input I have just `https://security.geobasis-bb.de/wss/service/VG-WFS/guest?` and for select Feature Type to Extract `bb`

Comment: What is the precise wording of the error message that you are receiving.  Does that WFS use the GML Simple Features profile?

Comment: Are you trying to do this from the ArcGIS Pro or ArcMap application of ArcGIS Desktop?  What are the precise steps that you are performing with one of the two service URLs that you have in your question body?